# Manipulate pixel colors to create a sunset

Tags: java, image, for-loop, pixel

I have to create a program that manipulates the color pixels of an image to create a look of a sunset in the background. I know to do this I have to increase the amount of the color red in the picture but whenever I program it it results in an error saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Color parameter outside of expected range: Red(in java.awt.Color)
```

My program looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class TrueColors2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Picture pictureObj = new Picture("WashingtonMonument.png");
       //picutreObj.explore();
       int redValue = 0; int greenValue = 0; int blueValue = 0;

       Pixel targetPixel = new Pixel(pictureObj, 0, 0);
       Color pixelColor = null;

       for(int y = 0; y < pictureObj.getHeight(); y++)
       {
           for(int x = 0; x < pictureObj.getWidth(); x++)
           {
               targetPixel = pictureObj.getPixel(x,y);
               pixelColor = targetPixel.getColor();

               redValue = pixelColor.getRed();
               greenValue = pixelColor.getGreen();
               blueValue = pixelColor.getBlue();

               pixelColor = new Color(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
               pixelColor = new Color(100 + pixelColor.getRed(),
                                      pixelColor.getGreen(),
                                      pixelColor.getBlue());
               targetPixel.setColor(pixelColor);

           }
       }


       pictureObj.write("ThirdWashingtonMonument.png");
       pictureObj.show();

   }   
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong and help me figure out how to create an effect of a sunset?
Thanks

Comment: As already pointed out, you are exceeding the allowed "red" component part. You could change it to `new Color(Math.min(255, 100 + pixelColor.getRed()), ...)`, but ... I'm not sure whether this is the desired effect. Just making the whole picture a bit redder will not look like a sunset, but ... like a reddish picture. If your question was how to create a sunset effect (and not why you receive the error), then you should elaborate this part a bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you add 100 to your red value, you're probably exceeding the maximum value of 255 at some point. You should consider inspecting the current value of `pixelColor.getRed()` before you add 100 to it.

Comment: What if there are multiple different red values around the picture? @swingMan

Comment: I'm sure there will be.  You'll  have to decide on the algorithm you want to use to give the desired effect. I'm just pointing out that whatever you decide,  you have to,make sure you don't exceed 255 when you provide the red value.